# What is the rationale behind NORAD's use of TEME?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, frames, sgp4

The most popular catalog of Earth-orbiting objects is NORAD’s. The catalog provides the so-called « two-line elements » (TLE) which essentially are computed orbital parameters of a catalogued object, for a given epoch. In turn, the parameters can be used to predict the position of said object at other instants not too remote from the epoch at which the TLE were computed.

One of the most puzzling aspects of NORAD’s approach is their choice of an Earth-centered inertial (ECI) reference frame called TEME, for « True Equator, Mean Equinox ». After trying to understand [what it means](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/44140/can-someone-explain-to-me-the-teme-reference-frame-in-defining-orbital-coordinat/44149#44149), and realizing [how complicated/sophisticated it is](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/55174/how-is-the-celestial-ephemeris-pole-cep-exactly-defined/55177?noredirect=1#comment184772_55177), I would like to address the question of the « why ? ».

This question can be decomposed into :

- What was NORAD’s rationale?
- What were the alternatives for NORAD at the time ?
- Was/is NORAD the only organization using TEME?
- Is it justified to keep using it ?

Comment: I think they would have to justify the effort to stop using it and switching to something else. That has real cost on something that is not 'necessary' for NORAD to do.

Comment: @Jon Custer, in your opinion, do they still use it internally? In other words, if somebody tells them to stop disseminating, they would still be stucked with TEME.

Comment: I have no basis to form an opinion one way or the other. I just know that changing processes is what is hard to justify - it is always easy to justify continuing to do what you are doing.

Comment: @Jon Custer, so you implied in fact that, internally, there are still using TEME. Otherwise, if they had changed to another reference for internal use, then continuing to support both, one for internal and one for dissemination, would be hard to justify.

Comment: It was not my intent to imply that - just that there is a current process to produce a dataset in a particular way, it works, why change it? That takes time, people, and funding...

Comment: @Jon Custer, "it works" can be opinion-based. For ex., « For various reasons, there is no consensus or authoritaitive definition for the [TEME] reference frame. Consequently, the use of TEME is not recommended, ... ». extract from [CCSDS Green Book 500x0g4, Nov 2019, p.22](https://public.ccsds.org/Pubs/500x0g4.pdf)

Comment: What I believe @JonCuster is saying is  "if it an't broken don't fix it."

Comment: @NgPh The TEME obviously does work for the low precision of the two line element sets for which the TEME is used. There is a cost to fixing things, especially if they "ain't broken".

Comment: Reading from here https://celestrak.com/columns/v02n01/ , in particular from the 8th paragraph, I seem to get the idea that at the time, there were methods/theory accurate enough to determine the position of the true equator, but not of the true equinox, so they decided to approximate it by the mean equinox (i.e., including only precession but not nutation of the vernal equinox).

Comment: @David Hammen, I am quite satisfied with the argument that fixing it (for better precision) isn't worth it (considering the other sources of errors in the TLE-SGP4 modelling). Nevertheless, it is frustrating that there has not been (to my knowledge) an effort for clarification and justification from authoritative sources; especially if it turns out that this concept is exclusive to TLE.

Comment: @Rafa, the hypothesis you put forward seems plausible. But it is hard for me to see how we can "connect the dots" between what TS Kelso wrote and your proposed explanation. Please feel free to write a "strawman" answer to the question on rationale.

Comment: Well, this sentence in particular _"Since observations of satellites are made by stations fixed to the Earth's surface, the elements generated will be referenced relative to the true equator. However, since the direction of vernal equinox is not tied to the Earth's surface, but rather to the Earth's orientation in space, an approximation must be made of its true direction."_ seems to imply that there was no issue in referencing coordinates to the true equator (seemingly because the movement of the true Equator is tied to the movement of the stations making the observations used to derive TLEs)

Comment: But on the other hand, referencing coordinates to the true equinox would have been not possible (at least not with enough accuracy) back then. I believe this is why TS Kelso makes emphasis here in differentiating between the orientation of the true equator (tied to the Earth's surface) and the orientation of the true equinox (not tied to Earth's surface)

Comment: @Rafa, I still have to digest the extract written by TS Kelso. But if the Equinox is the intersection of the Ecliptic with the Equator, then determining the Equator to a given accuracy should define also the Equinox to the same accuracy. What did I miss?

Comment: @NgPh that is a good point. I am now confused as well as to why the column by TS Kelso seems to make a distinction between having no problem to reference coordinates to the true equator, but being able to accurately determine the vernal equinox (at least with the same accuracy than for the true equator).

Comment: @Rafa, there is an equally plausible explanation, that is flip yours upside-down. There was no need for NORAD to refer to "true Equator" for TLE (a mean Equator would be enough for dissemination of TLE), but some "big boss", for obscure reasons, decided otherwise. Then, they got stuck and could neither justify nor give a clean definition. Just speculating to have all options on the table!